# How to set regexpFilterText and regexpFilterExpression in Jenkins generic trigger

Tags: jenkins

can everyone tell me, what doese this mean from jenkins generic trigger.

```
regexpFilterText("\$action-\$comment_body-\$changes_title_from")
regexpFilterExpression("^(opened|reopened|synchronize|created)|(edited-.+)\$^((r|R)ebuild)*")
```

My question is, what doese "-" mean in regexFilterText
How to give regexpFilterExpression multiple reguex?

My Goal is, the comment_body is only for "r(R)ebuild", and then jenkins will be triggered.